# Search for list with element inside list [Python 3]

Tags: python, list, search, python-3.x

Suppose I have list `A`, defined as `[['foo',1],['bar',2]]`. How would I find the list inside of `A` that has `'foo'` inside of it?

Comment: Well, let's back up: if we have a list, how do you know if an element is inside of it?

Comment: If the expression "if element in list" returns "True".

Comment: Okay, then, so how can you iterate through your list of lists to see if something is inside the innermost layer?

Comment: Ah, I would use a for loop to iterate for every item in the outermost list, and apply my previous method. Thank you!

Comment: You got some very complicated answers to a beginner question--make sure you understand what solution you go with.  Feel free to answer your own question with the solution you choose as best!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator expression to test each sublist. Since we just want the first, we can use the `next()` function on the genexp.

```
A = [['foo', 1], ['bar', 2]]
a = next(x for x in A if "foo" in x)
```

That gives you the sublist itself. If you want the index of the sublist instead:

```
a = next(i for i, x in enumerate(A) if "foo" in x)
```

Note that you might not actually need the index. You can do most things you'd want to do just having the list object. For example, if you want to replace the sublist entirely with `["baz", 3]`, you can do a slice assignment on it:

```
a = next(x for x in A if "foo" in x)
a[:] = ["baz", 3]
```

With either formulation, you'll get a `StopIteration` exception if the search term is not found. You can return `None` or whatever instead by using the second argument to `next()`. In this case, you must put parentheses around the genexp:

```
a = next((x for x in A if "foo" in x), None)
```

Comment: is there any preference between a[:] and list(a)? I generally choose the latter

Comment: On the left side of an `=` sign, `a[:]` is a slice assignment, not a copy. `list(a)` won't work on the left side of an `=`. For copying a list, `a[:]` is slightly faster than `list(a)` but you probably wouldn't notice in most cases. I would say in that case the issue is a matter of personal style. Any competent Python programmer would recognize either as being a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complicate things up, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> a = [['foo',1],['bar',2]]
>>> list(filter(lambda x:'foo'in x , a))
[['foo', 1]]
>>> a = [['foo',1],['bar',2],[1,'foo']]
>>> list(filter(lambda x:'foo'in x , a))
[['foo', 1], [1, 'foo']]
```